# Why do we find the Iron Wolves in Caldeum?

Tags: diablo-iii

Last time we saw the Iron Wolves, they were in Kurast, lending us a help with their warriors.

Why did they move to Caldeum? Is Asheara after the Evils too, or it's just a coincidence?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not all of them moved to Caldeum.

In the Diablo 3 Lore it mentions that:

**The Iron Wolves, lead by Asheara (from Diablo II), were hired to protect him until he was old enough to rule the city. The young ruler removed them and replaced them with his own Caldeum guards. Asheara is unsure of why he made this decision.**

"Him" meaning Emperor Hakan I, but nothing more is said about them.

Based on this, it would be possible to say that the Iron Wolves who were hired to help protect Emperor Hakan I were left to enforce order in the streets after Emperor Hakan II forced them out and replaced them with his own guards.